# Scripting FTP transfers

Tags: shell, shell-script, ftp

Is there a way to shebang-ify ftp and write small FTP scripts?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ftp
open 192.168.1.1
put *.gz
quit
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not with the `ftp` programs I've run into, as they expect a script on their standard input but a shebang would pass the script name on their command line.

You can use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to pass a script to `ftp` through a shell wrapper.

```
#!/bin/sh
ftp <<EOF
open 192.168.1.1
put *.gz
EOF
```

[Lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) accepts a script name passed as an argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/lftp -f
open 192.168.1.1
put *.gz
```

[Ncftp](http://www.ncftpd.com/ncftp/) comes with two tools `ncftpget` and `ncftpput` for simple batches of gets or puts.

[Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) includes an [FTP module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fzftp-Module). Using a proper shell rather than a straight FTP script has the advantage that you can react to failures.

```
#!/bin/zsh
zmodload zsh/zftp
open 192.168.1.1
put *.gz
```

Of course there are plenty of other languages you could use: Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.

Another approach is to mount the FTP server as a directory, and then use `cp` (or `rsync` or other tools) to copy files. There are many [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystems for FTP access, principally [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) and [LftpFS](http://lftpfs.sourceforge.net/).

Note that if you were planning to use authentication (likely if you're uploading), and you have control over the server, you'd be better off with SSH access. It's more secure and more flexible. To copy files over SSH, you can use `scp` or `sftp`, or [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) for efficient synchronization (if some of the files may already be there), or [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/stable/) (for bidirectional synchronization), or mount with [SshFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

Comment: Good answer, and to respond: The script I am trying to replace uses the "ftp <<EOF" method, which works and is fine, it just looks like the sort of pattern that shebangs attempt to abstract.